# What is the best AWS RDS Aurora import method for large datasets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to read about importing data into Aurora. It seems that importing sql or csv files with mysqlimport are the available options. Is there a way of copying the raw database files into RDS somehow or another faster method for very large databases?
If not what is the best way for very large datasets?

Answer (score 1):

AWS have [some options for migrating data into Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.html), which includes information about the fastest method to import data into Aurora. This section of the guide seems most relevant.

> You can copy the backup files from your database to an Amazon Simple
>   Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket, and then restore an Amazon Aurora
>   MySQL DB cluster from those files. **This option can be considerably
>   faster than migrating data using mysqldump**. For details, see
>   [Migrating Data from MySQL by Using an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.ExtMySQL.html#AuroraMySQL.Migrating.ExtMySQL.S3).